# how to get wifi state change Broadcast only once

Tags: android, android-wifi

In my application, I want to get wifi state change broadcast only once. However, when wifi changed, I received broadcast many times, what should I do?

```
public class WifiChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static String TAG = "WifiChangedReceiver";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    boolean isConnected = wifi != null && wifi.isConnected();
    if (isConnected) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        String wifi_ssid = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSSID();
        Log.d(TAG, "wifi  connected==="+wifi_ssid); 
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "wifi  disconnected"); 
    }
}


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WifiChangedReceiver mReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(mReceiver==null){
        mReceiver = new WifiChangedReceiver();
    }
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);    
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if(mReceiver!=null){
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

LogCat: wifi  Camus to Tutu
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ssdZ.png)

LogCat: wifi Tutu to Camus
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEXKX.png)

Comment: Try to unregistered after getting first time callback.

Comment: @Haresh Chhelana  I got the state at the same time, not one by one. and i need monitoring the state change until app exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all store a value in shared preference with value "off" and change the value of that during unregistering.so that it won't register again,so u don't get the broadcast again.

pf=preferenceManager.getdefaultsharedpreferences();

pf.edit().getString("status")

if(pf.getString(status).equals("off"))
{

register the receiver

}

Then during unregistering

{

pf.edit().putString("status","ON")

unregister the receiver

}

Comment: my problem is get the connected state twice or thrice at the same time, I have paste the Log printscreen.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by google,  although the reaction is not immediately, it's useful to my project. I posted the code, may be useful for somebody else.

```
public class WifiChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
            NetworkInfo netInfo = (NetworkInfo) b
                    .get(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            NetworkInfo.State state = netInfo.getState();
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if ((state == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) && (activeNetInfo != null)
                    && (activeNetInfo.getType() == netInfo.getType())) {
                Log.d(TAG, "wifi  connected"); 
            }
        }
    }
```